# After notebook upgrade got errors like this - TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'

Tags: jupyter-notebook

There was no error before I upgrade the notebook with some of the libraries (like panda and scipy, etc.), but from somewhere before I did those things, my notebook code shows many errors like this. The entire message from my notebook is as below;

```
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)

TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'
```

Comment: You should also share the code that causes the error

Comment: C:\Users\Chulwook Park\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    305                 pass
    306             else:
--> 307                 return printer(obj)
    308             # Finally look for special method names
    309             method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)
...

TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'

Comment: Please notice the initial part of the error as posted above. Also, regarding this problem, my notebook does not work with (ax = plt.gca()...). Actually, somewhere before I installed a couple of libraries with upgrades to simulate the COVID dashboard(data) via pip. After that, my notebook show many errors like this which were supposed to be no problem before it. Pretty sure it would be not a big problem but it really bothered me  whenever I try to simulate my notebook. Could you comment about this?